# What SFTP application just lets you drag and drop from desktop to the server?

Tags: sftp

Is there a single view SFTP client for Linux? All I have seen are dual window clients. I like the Windows ones like sftp and Cyberduck when you don't have a pointless view of your PC as you drag and drop from your desktop instead.

If there is a mode to switch to drag and drop single view I am wrong, but I don't see why these apps would be pushed as having two views as an advantage if you could simply customize them to only show the server. What would be the point of the view on your computer?

I am already looking at my computer. This is like having a cup-holder-holder

What SFTP application (with UI, not command line) just lets you drag and drop from desktop to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nautilus](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Nautilus?action=show&redirect=Nautilus), [ROX-Filer](http://rox.sourceforge.net/desktop/ROX-Filer), [Thunar](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/start), and essentially anything else using [GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/)/the GNOME VFS supports this, as do [Dolphin](https://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin) and [Konqueror](https://konqueror.org) and essentially anything else using KDE's [KIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIO) layer.

Probably you are already using one of these to look at your computer.

You can also use [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) to mount a remote SFTP server in a directory on your machine, and then use any file manager at all to manipulate the files as though they were local.

Comment: Wow you are right that's infinitely cool